# Visual Studio 2015 - How to type {

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-2015

I have got a french keyboard and am unable to type `{`. A shorcut is bound to it that pops the *Task Runner Explorer* (or focuses it).

The shortcut on my keyboard is `Alt Gr`+`$`

I've been looking into `Tools -> Options -> Keyboard` but haven't found where to unbind this shortcut - how can I do this ?

Comment: Title says `{` but question says `}` make your mind up

Comment: Oops - correcting this.